# How to restrict users from opening more than one browser tab (window) within same session?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, session

I have developed an ASP.NET MVC 3 website, and I am using TempData at various places. I would like my users not to open more than one tab/ window of the browser within same session to avoid conflicts in session data. How to impose this restriction?

Comment: I may be missing your point, but understand tempdata has nothing to do with session.

Comment: No, tempdata is using session in background. However, tempdata gets erased (unless if we explicitly retain them using .Keep method).

Comment: IC. didn't realize. Read this, maybe interesting http://www.gregshackles.com/2010/07/asp-net-mvc-do-you-know-where-your-tempdata-is/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible in general. You don't have any information on a server side about how many windows are opened on a client side. Moreover, if you have a need to restrict users from opening more that one window then you definitly doing something wrong because it is a nature of web applications to work in several windows.

However you *can* reduce a possibility of this by making your application fully in AJAX (one page applications they are named). So users just won't be able to open several windows except by opening the start page of your application manually in another tab. But you cat't do anything abouth this. And once againg - it is truly a very bad desing.